# Facebook Android API - Requesting paged results returns null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to request all the messages from a Facebook Messenger thread, and pagination is proving troublesome for me.

```
        new Request(session,"293222697487222",null, HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            try {
                if(response!=null) {
                    GraphObject asdf = response.getGraphObject();

                    JSONObject arr = asdf.getInnerJSONObject();

                    JSONArray array = arr.getJSONObject("comments").getJSONArray("data");

                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                    {
                        Log.i("MESSAGE "+ i, array.getJSONObject(i).getString("message"));
                    }

                    Request next = response.getRequestForPagedResults(Response.PagingDirection.NEXT);
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
    ).executeAsync();
```

So my first part is working correctly, and giving me the messages that I'm looking for correctly. When I take the response to get the request for the next page of results, the request is always null. I KNOW for a fact that it shouldn't be null as I've checked this thread in the Graph API explorer and did both NEXT and PREVIOUS - the next and previous fields exist, but it's still giving me null for some reason.

Can anybody help me out?